# Optimizing image acquisition with Matlab parallel computing toolbox tools

Tags: image-processing, parallel-processing, video-capture, matlab

Using a single matlab worker I easily can achieve maximal frames per seconds (fps) of with my camera (using matlab imaq toolbox). This simple code does it:

```
matlabpool(1)
start(vid)
pause(1); % give matlab time to initialize the camera
for j=1:frames
     data = getsnapshot(vid);
end
```

However, once I try to do some image processing on the fly, the effective rate drops by 50%. Since I have 5 more workers in the matlabpool (and also a gpu), can I optimize this such that each frame grabbed will be processed by a different worker? for example:

```
for j=1:frames
data = getsnapshot(vid);
      <do some analysis with worker mod((j),5)+2  i.e. worker 2 to 6 >  
end
```

the issue is the 'data' is serially obtained from the camera, and the analysis takes about 2 rounds of the loop, so if a different worker (or core) would take care of that each time, the maximum fps can be obtain again...

Comment: I'm confused.  Why do you only have a matlabpool(1)?

Comment: That was just to restrict the code to one worker, to prove that one core is enough to handle the camera, hence the rest should handle the processing...

Comment: also what are you doing with the processed images? If you are displaying them in a figure, then you have to think about whether it's possible to update the GUI from multiple workers..

Comment: Obsolete isn't a reason to delete a question. Often there are people stuck with the obsolete version for a long time to come and you can always use this question/answer to signpost the better solution too.

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it, the workflow here is serial by nature..

Best you can do is to vectorize/parallelize your image processing function (so you still grab images one-by-one, but you distribute the processing on multiple cores)

Comment: The image is processed using various standard functions: threshold (i.e. 'image=image.*(image>threshold)' ) , conv2 with a filter, and peak detection using a simple local maxima finder. At the moment the processing code i use is pretty fast, but doesn't gain speed if I use more than one core (I've checked that with matlabpool(1)). Using a gpu might help, but there is the price of casting the variables each time to gdouble etc. So, I ask if a possible solution could be to analyze each event (or image) that arrives serially with a different core? or image1 by core1, image2 by core2 etc...

Comment: @wavepacket: I'm just brainstorming here, but perhaps you can have a buffer/queue were you store incoming images. It would be continually filled using a [timer](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/timer.html) object with a certain interval. Think of this as running in the background. On the other hand, your code will process this queue of images in parallel; You fetch images from the queue one at a time, dispatching each to one worker, which should place the result on another queue of processed images.

Comment: @wavepacket: [...]. Finally you can have a second timer that display images in order (assuming the worker in charge finished, otherwise wait for the next iteration) with a interval matching the desired frame rate (FPS). Again this is only an idea, not sure if it is even possible to implement :) HTH

Answer (score 1):

I think I got the solution:

```
for i=1:frames

     for sf=1:6; % I got 6 cores
         m(:,:,sf) = getsnapshot(vid);
     end

     spmd 
         result=f(m(:,:,labindex));
     end
end
```

I manange to get better results with GPU parallelization though...